# A base for a topology on Naturals

Tags: general-topology

Let $\mathbb{N}$ be the positive natural numbers set and let
$S_{n}=\{n,n+1,n+2,…\}$ for every $n\in\mathbb{N}$. I would like to show that the family $\mathcal{B}=\{B\subset\mathbb{N} : \exists n\in\mathbb{N}, S_{n}\subset B\}$ is a base for a topology on $\mathbb{N}$. For showing that I must show that:

a) $\bigcup_{B\in\mathcal{B}} B=\mathbb{N}$

b) For every $B_{1},B_{2}\in\mathcal{B}$ and for every $m\in B_{1}\cap B_{2}$, there exists a $B_{m}\in\mathcal{B}$ such that $m\in B_{m}\subset B_{1}\cap B_{2}$

For this a) is not hard so see since $S_{1}\in\mathcal{B}$.

For b) from the definition of $B$, there exists $S_{n_{1}}$ and $S_{n_{2}}$ such that $S_{n_{1}}\subset B_{1}$ and $S_{n_{2}}\subset B_{2}$. For every $m\in B_{1}\cap B_{2}$, if
$\max\{n_{1},n_{2}\}=n_{1}$, then choose $B_{m}=\{m\}\cup S_{n_{1}}$.

Is this my proof correct? Any help, hint, short way would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Looks correct to me.

Comment: To me also. Fyi, this is the cofinite topology on $\Bbb N.$ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cofiniteness#Cofinite_topology

Comment: Thank you very much @AnneBauval

Comment: Thank you very much and for editing @StevenClontz